# Why do external functions get executed immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a declared function in my code. I want to call this function whenever I click on an item. When I bind it to this item, it gets executed immediately, and the on click event does not trigger.

However, when I declare the function in the on click binding, it works fine.

I want to declare the function somewhere else first, and then call it when the click event happens

```
function test2() {
  alert('test2');
}

$('body').on('click', '#test1', function() { alert('test1'); });
$('body').on('click', '#test2', test2());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ag66r950/

Comment: You're binding to the return value of `test2` (which is `undefined`).  You need to just use `$('body').on('click', '#test2', test2);`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('body').on('click', '#test1', function() { alert('test1'); });
```

This is passing function handle as parameter, not the function result itself

while

```
$('body').on('click', '#test2', test2());
```

This is passing result of function execution as a parameter not the function itself.

You need to pass the handle of funciton itself in the event handler

```
$('body').on('click', '#test2', test2);
```